# Deepcopy does not work on dataframe containing lists? How to resolve

Tags: python, dataframe, copy

I am trying to copy a dataframe which contains lists. On the copied DF I have to apply modifications to the lists, however also the original lists get modified, which is not what I want. I have tried:

- DF.copy()
- DF.copy(deep=True)
- copy.deepcopy(DF)
- DF.apply(copy.deepcopy)

but none work. To my understanding, deepcopy does not work on dataframes containing mutable objects.
This is a sample code I found on the web:

```
>>> import copy
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'q': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'w': [1, 2, [3, 4, 5]]})
>>> df
   q          w
0  a          1
1  b          2
2  c  [3, 4, 5]
>>> df_c = df.apply(copy.deepcopy)
>>> df_c
   q          w
0  a          1
1  b          2
2  c  [3, 4, 5]
>>> del df_c.loc[2, 'w'][0]
>>> df_c
   q       w
0  a       1
1  b       2
2  c  [4, 5]
>>> df
   q       w
0  a       1
1  b       2
2  c  [4, 5]
```

Is there a way to make a real deepcopy on this kind of DF? Or how would you manage this situation?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, deepcopy does not copy the lists within your dataframe.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html
"Note that when copying an object containing Python objects, a deep copy will copy the data, but will not do so recursively. Updating a nested data object will be reflected in the deep copy."

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'q': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'w': [1, 2, [3, 4, 5]]})
>>> df
   q          w
0  a          1
1  b          2
2  c  [3, 4, 5]

# Use this method to avoid importing copy.
df_c = df.copy(deep=True)
# Make a new list to avoid the issue.
new_list = df_c.loc[2, 'w']
# Do what you need to with it.
df_c.loc[2, 'w'] = new_list[1:3]
>>> df_c
   q       w
0  a       1
1  b       2
2  c  [4, 5]
>>> df
   q          w
0  a          1
1  b          2
2  c  [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Finally, thank you. My actual situation was slightly more complicated and the code pretty intricated so the meaning of "updating the object" wasn't straightforward to me. My actual code applies a map to a dataframe copy column. So if anyone needs this, the solution was: within the map function map_func(x) I copied the cell content to x_copy = copy.deepcopy(x) , applied the necessary modifications to x_copy and then for example returned it from the function as return x_copy.